# Jquery autocomplete from database countries

Tags: php, jquery, database, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm having trouble with completing an autocomplete function in Jquery with data from database. Whenever I type something I always get 'no results found' message. I want it to display a country name as the user is typing.

jquery.php

```
  <?php
require "database/database.php";
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p><label>Country:</label><input type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.auto').autocomplete({
                    source:"suggested.php",
                    MinLength: 2
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my suggested.php page:

```
   <?php
require "database/database.php";
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE countryname LIKE '%".$term."%'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        $data[] = array(
        'label' = $row['countryname'],
        'value' = $row['countryname']
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
    flush();
}
?>
```

In the database I have a table named countries and within it countryid, countryname and countryflag. I need to extract only the countryname column.
I've tried using $_GET['term'] and $_REQUEST['term'].
I've tried different tutorials but none of them seems to work.
If you have any suggestions please tell me. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will be delay your execution if you run query in every time when you type,because you can input value as a query condition value! 
`I can give you some I tested logic is run your query first when document is loaded and store as a json data type,then you can set source data in autocomplete`

> This can reduce your page delay respond time by sql query running

```
     <form action="" method="post">
        <p><label>Country:</label><input type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var source = [];
            $.ajax({
                  url : "suggested.php",
                  data : "GET",
                  dataType : "json",
                  success : function(data){
                       for(var i in data){
                           source.push(data[i]);
                        }
                  }
                 });
            $('.auto').autocomplete({
                source: source,
                MinLength: 2
            });
        });

    </script>
```

suggested.php

```
   <?php
   require "database/database.php";       
   $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries");
   $result = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $result[] = array(
    'label' = $row['countryname'],
    'value' = $row['countryname']
    );
}
echo json_encode($result);
flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey David, thank you for your suggestion. However I still get the same result ('no results found').

Comment: How and where can I check it?

Comment: from browser developer tools,you can see it on network tab

Comment: I've tried running suggested.php only and it seems there's a mistake there. I'll have a look into that.

Comment: suggesed.php is now without any errors however I still managed to get the result I'm looking for. I get 'no search results' everytime I start typing.

Comment: try var_dump() of suggesed.php result .what array type getting?

Comment: It displays resource(5) of type (mysql result)

Comment: it's sound like you need to learn more ajax ,autocomplete and sql fetching from online tutorials,after then you can ask specific error with details :)

Comment: @davidb What was your mistake in your php file? My issue is that when I run echo json_encode($array); nothing is printed out